# jQuery m custom scrollbar parallax

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, parallax, m

I wanted to add parallax effect (different scroll speed) to jQuery custom scroll bar plugin (mCustomScrollbar). I'm combining two examples of code:

1. http://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie - different scrolling speeds
2. manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/full_page_demo.html - Full page scroller

See also - http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ (plugin callbacks / functions)

I have managed to make both examples work separately, but not together, I have end up with this:

```
j(window).load(function(){

j("body").mCustomScrollbar({
scrollButtons:{
enable:true
},

callbacks:{

onScrollStart:function(){ myCallback(this,"#onScrollStart") },

onScroll:function(){ 

  var boxes = j('[data-scroll-speed]'),
      jwindow = this.mcs.content;

  var scrollTop = this.mcs.top;

      boxes.each(function(){
      var jthis = j(this),
      scrollspeed = parseInt(jthis.data('scroll-speed')),
      val = - scrollTop / scrollspeed;
      jthis.css('transform', 'translateY(' + val + 'px)');
      });

                },

        whileScrolling:function(){

                    },
alwaysTriggerOffsets:false
 }

});

});
```

Elements html is:

```
img src="http://www.somedomain.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/first-bg.png" alt="first-bg" width="800" height="582" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-678 para" data-scroll-speed="7" />
```

/* Note data-scroll-speed="7" - this img element needs to have different scroll speed  */

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you describe what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Images with data-scroll-speed="7"  should move at different speed on scroll.